# Show only form when open excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel xlsm file with a form. I want when I open the file to see only the form.
I tried to hide application with the following line:

```
   application.visible = false
```

But if I have already open excel files, they also become invisible.

So does anyone know how to see only the form when I open the file with no changes in other open excel files? Or open this file in new instance /note: I work on vitual machine, so I can't make changes on Windows Registry/

Comment: It sounds like you are writing an application. It might be time for you to try VB.NET. You can automate Excel from VB.NET plus anything else you could imagine. See how easy it can be: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-visual-basic-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this with 3 excel windows open. The window containing the macro closes and reopens without affecting the other 2 open books

```
Sub win()
    Dim myWindow1 As Window
    'Set myWindow1 = ActiveWindow
    ' make sure you get *this* workbooks window
    Set myWindow1 = ThisWorkbook.Windows(1)

    With myWindow1
      .Visible = False
    End With

    MsgBox "Hi"

    With myWindow1
      .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub
```